# Call a function with an array which holds array of parameters instead of listing just arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Excuse the badly composed title, but what I'm asking is this:

Say you have a function like this:

```
function cartesianProductOf() {
      return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function(a, b) {
        var ret = [];
        a.forEach(function(a) {
          b.forEach(function(b) {
            ret.push(a.concat([b]));
          });
        });
        return ret;
      }, [[]]);
}
```

which is to be called like this:

```
cartesianProductOf([1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6], ['a','b']);
```

The problem which I'm facing is that I make a dynamic array and I basically have an array which holds the arguments which should be sent to the function, like this:

```
var sets = [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6], ['a','b']];
```

Now, of course, the call:

```
cartesianProductOf(sets);
```

will not work. True, I can modify the cartesianProductOf() function easily to this (only important part shown):

```
function cartesianProductOf() {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments[0], function(a, b) {
```

But I'm wondering is there a way in javascript that I would call `cartesianProductOf` with `sets` variable, without having to change the code of `cartesianProductOf` to accept arguments[0]? Also, I would appreciate the change in title to the more appropriate one (as I've been searching for that keywords around the site, and clearly it's wrong as I couldn't find no relevant info).

Comment: Are you looking for [`cartesianProductOf.apply(null, sets)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: how to pass array-values as arguments to a function to be read using Function::arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939216/javascript-how-to-pass-array-values-as-arguments-to-a-function-to-be-read-using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [DCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233508/dcoder) answered in the comment - I had to use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method like this:

```
cartesianProductOf.apply(null, sets)
```

The difference between `apply` and `call` functions in JavaScript is well explained in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply), and to quote:

> The main difference is that apply lets you invoke the function with
>   arguments as an array; call requires the parameters be listed
>   explicitly.